# I need a Swift code for this C# Code

Tags: c#, ios, swift

I have written a rest service in C#(Xamarin) that gets me a token from API. I need the same code in Swift, I tried to look here and there but couldn't find anything solid. Have a look at the code below

```
public class RestService
{

    HttpClient client;

    public RestService()
    {
        client = new HttpClient();
        client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 256000;
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded "));
    }
    public async Task<Token> Login(User user)
    {
        string webUrl = Utility.AppConstant.ApiUrl + "/token";
        var postData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"));
        postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", user.Username));
        postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", user.Password));
        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);
        var response = await PostResponseLogin<Token>(webUrl, content);
        return response;
    }
    public async Task<T> PostResponseLogin<T>(string webUrl, FormUrlEncodedContent content) where T : class
    {
        try
        {
            var response = await client.PostAsync(webUrl, content);
            var jsonResult = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            var responseObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonResult);
            return responseObject;
        }
        catch 
        { return null; }
    }
```

Comment: Was there something in particular that you couldn't figure out how to do? We're not going to write it for you

Comment: I'm afraid that here is not a code outsourcing

Comment: There are countless Swift examples of this.  You probably won't get someone here to rewrite your code to Swift though.

Answer (score 0):

[Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) makes it really easy.

Your login code would look something like this:

```
let parameters: Parameters = [
      "grant_type":"password",
      "username":user.Username,
      "password":user.Password
   ]
Alamofire.request(AppConstant.ApiUrl + "/token", method: .post, parameters: parameters) response in {

    // do something with the response

}
```

There are a ton of options for just about anything you need, include deserialization.

Comment: the content in my C# code gets Encoded with the statement
  var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData); 
. Will  Alamofire.request(AppConstant.ApiUrl + "/token", method: .post, parameters: parameters) response in {
} do the same ?

Comment: I believe that form url encoding is the default, but you can specify it with the encoding parameter. https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#parameter-encoding